# Print every nth column of a file

Tags: awk

I have a rather big file with 255 coma separated columns and I need to print out every third column only.

I was trying something like this

```
awk '{ for (i=0;i<=NF;i+=3) print $i }' file
```

but that doesn't seem to be the solution, since it prints to only one long column. Anybody can help? Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Here is one way to do this.

The script prog.awk:

```
BEGIN {FS = ","} # field separator
{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i += 3) printf ("%s%c", $i, i + 3 <= NF ? "," : "\n");}
```

Invocation:

```
awk -f prog.awk <input.csv >output.csv
```

Example input.csv:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
```

Example output.csv:

```
1,4,7,10
11,14,17,20
```

Comment: +1 for beating me in 39sec!! `awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=2)printf "%s%s", $i, (i+3>NF?"\n":FS)}' `

Comment: Can someone please explain (i+3>NF?"\n":FS) part ? @Kent

Comment: @Kent If we print the last item (`i + 3` is greater than the number of fields), print a newline. Otherwise, print a comma (field separator). `NF` is number of fields, `FS` is field separator.

Answer (score 7):

It behaves like that because by default [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) splits fields in spaces. You have to tell it to split them with commas, and it's done using the `FS` variable or the `-F` switch. Besides that, first field is number one. The zero is the whole line, so also change the initial value of the `for` loop:

```
awk -F',' '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=3) print $i }' file
```