# Extracting same column from each file to one file

Tags: awk, paste, cut

I have the following dataset with 171 files.

```
CHR:POS   REF:ALT   BREED

6:85406127 T:A 0.333333
6:85406128 T:C 0
6:85406129 C:G 0.333333
6:85406130 T:G 0.833333
```

Desired output is

```
CHR:POS   REF:ALT   BREED BREED2 BREED3 ... 171st file

6:85406127 T:A 0.333333 0.33 0.5 .... 0.4
6:85406128 T:C NA 0.33 0.5 .... 0.4
6:85406129 C:G 0.333333 0.33 NA .... 0
6:85406130 T:G 0.833333 0.33 0.5 .... NA
```

The filenames contain the breed names. The first and second columns contain the same information in every file. How I am going to extract only the third column from each file while keeping all columns from the first file?

I moved the first file into other folder to exclude from the extraction. The following command did not give the result.

```
cut -d " " -f3 *.txt | paste ../breedname.txt - > output.txt
```

I also had attempts using awk command shown in these questions, but it did not work for my dataset.

- [paste same column from multiple files into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28281605/paste-same-column-from-multiple-files-into-one)
- [Print every nth column of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22354082/print-every-nth-column-of-a-file)

Any help is welcomed!

Comment: Welcome to SO and special thanks for showing your attempts, keep it up. Could you please confirm once if your all file's 1st 2 fields will be same or not?

Comment: Thanks for a kind welcome! Yes, the first and second fields are same in each file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very quick and dirty way of doing it:

**Assuming your files are in the same order:**

```
$ awk '(FNR==NR){a[FNR]=$0;next}
       {a[FNR]=a[FNR] FS $NF}
       END{for(i=1;i<=FNR;++i) print a[i]}' file1 file2 file3 ... filen
```

if you want the header a bit cleaner:

```
$ awk '(FNR==NR){a[FNR]=$0 (FNR==1?++c:"");next}
       {a[FNR]=a[FNR] FS $NF (FNR==1?++c:"")}
       END{for(i=1;i<=FNR;++i) print a[i]}' file1 file2 file3 ... filen
```

**Assuming your files are not in the same order:**

```
$ awk '{key=$1 FS $2}
       (FNR==NR){a[key]=$0 (FNR==1?++c:"");next}
       {a[key]=a[key] FS $NF (FNR==1?++c:"")}
       END{for(i in a) print a[i]}' file1 file2 file3 ... filen
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
paste -d " " *.txt | awk '{printf "%s %s ",$1,$2; for (i = 3; i <= NF; i+=3){printf "%s ",$i} print ""}'
```

`paste` joins the lines vertically, so you would have every column next to each other. After that, you just have to select the required columns.

Comment: Thanks for the command! The values in the third column don't show up in the output. Output has only the repeats of the third column of the first file.